# Observing LiveData in JetPack Composable

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am practicing JetPack Compose with a pet app and I'm trying to observe a loading state in a Splash screen via LiveData. But, inside my composable I am asked to provide **viewLifecycleOwner** which seems impossible inside a composable. Or do I need to pass it down from the MainActivity? Seems clunky, is there another, more Jetpacky way?

```
@Composable
fun SplashScreen(navController: NavHostController, isLoadingInit: LiveData<Boolean>) {
    val scale = remember {
        Animatable(0f)
    }
    
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = true) {
        scale.animateTo(
            targetValue = 0.5f,
            animationSpec = tween(
                durationMillis = 500,
                easing = {
                    OvershootInterpolator(2f).getInterpolation(it)
                }
            )
        )
    }

    Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.Center, modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.pokeball),
            contentDescription = "Pokemon Splashscreen",
            modifier = Modifier.scale(scale.value)
        )
    }

    isLoadingInit.observe(**viewLifecycleOwner**) {
        navController.navigate("main-screen")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert your `LiveData` to `State` using `LiveData.observeAsState()` extension function. Also instead of passing a `LiveData` as a parameter to compose, prefer converting it to a `State` first and then pass that as a parameter.

```kotlin
// This is probably what you are doing right now (inside a NavGraph)
val isLoadingInit = viewModel.isLoadingInit
SplashScreen(navController, isLoadingInit)
```

Change it to:

```kotlin
val isLoadingInit by viewModel.isLoadingInit.observeAsState()
SplashScreen(navController, isLoadingInit)
```

And then,

```kotlin
@Composable
fun SplashScreen(navController: NavHostController, isLoadingInit: Boolean) {
    LaunchedEffect(isLoadingInit) {
        if(!isLoadingInit) // Or maybe its negation
            navController.navigate("main-screen")
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you